# asp.net - How can I successfully update a gridview (or listview) that has been dynamically generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

In the code behind I am collecting information from the database, and then with a loop, displaying that info in different tables. I would like to make it so the user of the site is able to update the "Users" and "Notes" fields for each row.

Portion of Environments.aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="Panel1" 
                    OnItemDataBound="ListView_ItemDataBound" CellSpacing="2" 
                    CellPadding="2" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1"></asp:Panel>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <br />
                        <%#Eval("Name") %> (Database: <%#Eval("Database") %>): 
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="180000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
                        </asp:Timer>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="800" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="LinkAddress" DataTextField="ServerName" HeaderText="Server:" Target="_blank" ItemStyle-Width="200" />
                                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="ServerName" HeaderText="Server:" />--%>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Environment" HeaderText="Environment" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Users" HeaderText="Users" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Build" HeaderText="Build" ItemStyle-Width="200" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" 
                            Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                            Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="EditRow" 
                                Text="Edit" Visible='<%# PrivilegedUser() %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

Portion of Environments.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView ListView1;
    ListView1 = (ListView)LoginView2.FindControl("ListView1");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = Envs;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView ListView1;
    ListView1 = (ListView)LoginView2.FindControl("ListView1");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = Envs;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected Boolean PrivilegedUser()
{
    SQLConnections SQL = new SQLConnections();
    bool IsPrivileged = SQL.IsUserPrivileged();
    return IsPrivileged;
}

public class Environment
{
    public int EnvId { get; set; }
    public string LineBreak { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public List<Svrs> Svrs { get; set; }
}

public class Svrs
{
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string Environment { get; set; }
    public string Users { get; set; }
    public string Build { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string LinkAddress { get; set; }
}

public List<Environment> Envs
{
    get
    {
        string[] EnvList = GetEnvs();
        List<string> ServerList = GetServers();
        string[,] DBNamesAndServers = GetDBNamesAndServers();
        string[] DBServers = GetDataBaseServer(DBNamesAndServers);
        string[] DBNames = GetDataBaseName(DBNamesAndServers);
        int num = EnvList.Count();
        List<Environment> CompleteEnvList = new List<Environment>();
        List<Environment> CompleteServerList = new List<Environment>();
        List<Environment> CompleteTempList = new List<Environment>();
        int i = 0;
        int z = 1;

        while(i<num)
        {
            string envname = EnvList[i];
            string dbserver = "Unknown";
            int index = 0;
            if (DBNames.Contains(EnvList[i]))
            {
                index = Array.IndexOf(DBNames, EnvList[i]);
                dbserver = (DBServers[index]);
            }
            string[,] CurServerInfo = GetSvrs(ServerList, envname);
            List<Svrs> NewSvr = new List<Svrs>();
            NewSvr.AddRange(NewSvrInfo(CurServerInfo, z));
            Environment CurrentSvr = new Environment();
            Environment CurrentEnv = new Environment();

                CurrentSvr = new Environment
                    {
                        EnvId = i+1,
                        LineBreak = "",
                        Name = envname,
                        Database = dbserver,
                        Svrs = NewSvr,
                    };
                CompleteServerList.Add(CurrentSvr);

            CompleteEnvList.AddRange(CompleteServerList);
            i++;
            z = z + 10;
        }

        return CompleteServerList; //CompleteEnvList;
    }
}
```

At the moment, when I click on the "Edit" link, the page just refreshes. I need to be able to know the values of "Environment", "Users" and "Notes" for the row the user is updating, so I can actually update the database and have the table refreshed. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you stepped thru the code..? if so where are the values not showing up which line ?

Comment: As per Sagar's solution you can use, them. It will be ok you have to alter simply some fields,.....